# How serial up-voting is decided?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

I noticed on Jan 6 more than 1000 of my reputation was reduced by removing some users. I have never, ever created any other user or up-voted myself through any mechanism.

It is at least my right to know exactly how a serial up/down voting is decided? If some user likes the common logic of the other user's questions and answers and up-votes them is this is fraud serial up-voting? What have been that removed users and how the admins decided their up-voting has been kind of fraud?

Comment: I can't go into too much detail on the serial upvoting detection system, because giving out details is likely to allow people to avoid detection in the future. In this case, the voters planned their votes carefully to avoid detection for a long time. But newer tests (designed to catch voting rings on Stack Overflow) discovered them. Moderators can't see votes, much less invalidate them, so there's no opening for personal opinions to be at play. And just to be clear, you were certainly an innocent bystander.